# Genealogytree/tcolorbox - Passing a command as a parameter to a node

Tags: tcolorbox, genealogytree

Using the `genealogytree` package (based on the `tcolorbox` package), I am trying to pass a command as an option to a given node.

In the MWE below, the option `box={colback=MyColor}` can be passed to the node `Parent` but the same parameter, saved into the command `\Child` cannot be passed to the node `Child`.

Can someone explain me how to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\Child}{box={colback=red!30}}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree{
            child{
                g[box={colback=blue!30}]{Parent}
                c[\Child]{Child}
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand `\Child` once before you let PGFKeys parse it.

This can be done with the `/tikz/style` key and the `.expand once` handler, for easier access I define a `/gtr/style` that uses those without you having to explicitly write `.expand once` each time.

However, since it's PGFKeys you should just use a style directly, e.g.

```
Child/.style={box={colback=red!30}}
```

which I have done in the first diagram.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{genealogytree}
\gtrset{style/.style={/tikz/style/.expand once={#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[% or \gtrset{Child/.style={…}} in the preamble
 Child/.style={box={colback=red!30}}
]{
    child{
        g[box={colback=blue!30}]{Parent}
        c[Child]{Child}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\Child}{box={colback=red!30}}
\genealogytree{
    child{
        g[box={colback=blue!30}]{Parent}
        c[style=\Child]{Child}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's also `options for node={Child}{box={colback=red!30}}` and the `c[id=Child]`, see also subsection 5.1.1 of the manual.

Comment: I had noticed this option but I have too many families mixing together to make the use of `options for node=` easy.